# How do I decide the properties of this ferrite bead value

Tags: microcontroller, power, pcb-design

[image]

There is such a circuit in a microcontroller datasheet and it is said that we should use a ferrite bead for AVDD. How do I decide the properties of this ferrite bead value?

Comment: Which MCU? Almost certainly unimportant; perhaps 300R or higher would be fine.

Comment: @TimWilliams NUVOTON MCUs

Comment: @TimWilliams How do i decide freq ?

Comment: You don't design the frequency. Ferrite beads are rated to have some impedance at some frequency. You look at Nuvoton examples to find what value they used. It may be found in the BOM for that board you have the schematics.

Comment: @Justme Since no examples of ferrite bead value are given in the Nuvoton schematics, I asked here

Comment: What levels of high-frequency attenuation are you expecting? What chief area of the spectrum are you hoping to target? What DC currents are involved? If you can't answer all of these, speak with the MCU supplier.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm not trying to make a high-end board I'm just going to make a development board. Would it be a problem without the ferrite bead?

Comment: I can't say whether it'll be a problem or not. It will function with a short circuit instead of the FBs but, whether you will get a noisy signal I can't say.

Comment: @Andyaka Ok, Thank youu